# Redirect a php url to shtml in IIS7 using the web.config file

Tags: php, redirect, iis-7

The entire site I recently built goes down every time I try to redirect a path with index.php in it.

Any suggestions on what's causing the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Code:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
     <system.webServer>
         <defaultDocument>
             <files>
                 <add value="index.shtml" />
             </files>
         </defaultDocument>
     </system.webServer>
     <location path="index.php/terms-of-use/">
          <system.webServer>
             <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.nortridge.com/legal-disclaimer.shtml" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
          </system.webServer>
     </location>
</configuration>
```